# Quero alertar um outro APP, com Ionic 3 e Cordova 8

Tags: ionic3

Olá!

Quero mandar um alerta de um app para o outro, estou desenvolvendo os dois e eles já conversam, mas não consegui fazer essa questão do alerta.

```
<ion-item style="align-items: center;">
      <button color="green" ion-button (click)="presentAlert()">
        <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>&nbsp; {{'o que quer alertar?' | translate}}
      </button>
    </ion-item>

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: '!!* Atenção *!!',
    subTitle: 'Uma mensagem de alerta!',
    buttons: ['Já vou ver...']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

No próprio app, funciona normal. Como eu faria pra enviar para o outro app?